# The 'number of months' challenge

Tags: logical-deduction, riddle

Okay, here I am having a puzzle for you all. The puzzle is quite short and clear in it's own way I am telling you. Rather than a question it's more like a challenge to you all (*answer is already known*).

The Puzzle is:

> *Some months have 31 days; how many have 28?*

Answer with appropriate explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivial

Comment: This is way too easy, nice try though ;).

Comment: All months have 28 days; some just have a few more.

Comment: Remember kids: Playing tricks with imprecise questioning is not fun!

Comment: Zero. You never specified what type of "day" you mean: SI or "Mewtime". For me, one of your months is one of my days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is

> 12 months
> All months have at least 28 days